# Import virtual disk to Google Cloud with Custom network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vmdk

When I try to import a `vmdk` file to GCP with `gcloud compute images import`  command, I get

> "googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0]': ''.
>
> Subnetwork should be specified for custom subnetmode network".

The subnet mode in default network is set to "CUSTOM".  that's why I am getting that msg.

Is there a way to specify network when I import the image?  or specify the subnet information?

Comment: This does seems like a defect within the GCP platform. 
For further investigating this issue, I would recommend you to open a defect report using the [issue-tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_bugs_and_feature_requests_by_product). While opening the report, try to mention all the details including the reproduction steps. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Please follow [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/116701145) public issue tracker link for further updates on this issue.You could provide your comments/suggestion over there as well.

Comment: thanks, I will follow that link for update.

Answer (score 1):

## Suggestion:

This workaround worked for me, you can do it while this issue is still not solved:

- create a temp project, a default auto network will be created automatically.
- import the vmdk to the temp project
- In your original project, create instance using the imported image.
- Delete temp project

Note: Deleting the temp project will delete the imported image, but not the created instance.